# Leaking spigot assembly

Tags: first-time-brewer

I just brewed my first batch with a Mr Beer 8 liter kit. However, it seems that i made a rookie mistake about assembling the spigot. It leaks as small drops.

Do you think that the spigot can be tightened without ruining the end product or that it is already ruined and it will be a waste of a HME?

EDIT: The leaking stopped by itself overnight. I put a paper towel underneath the spigot and it's been dry for two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening and exposing the beer to outside air while it is fermenting will risk infection, though a leak means that it is exposed any how.

Not sure what your spigot setup looks like, but if you can try to tighten it without opening the vessel, I'd say give it a shot.

Comment: Maybe try to create a temporary seal. Try to seal the leak with candle wax. It should not affect the beer, minimize the amount of air that comes in contact with the beer and... save beer!

Answer (score 1):

You could try tightening it by turning the spigot itself clockwise from the outside. It'll end up cattywampus, but at least it won't be leaking.

When I install things like this (bottling bucket spigot, weldless kettle valve, mash tun valve, etc.) I initially install the valve between 45 and 90 degrees off from vertical, tighten the inside nut, and then tighten the valve from the outside to get a nice seal. I've never had any leaks using this method.